# Mobile Safari - translate3d pixel limit?

Tags: ios, mobile, css, iphone-web-app, webkit-transform

I have the following HTML structure

```
<body>
  <div id="graphic">
   <div id="wrap">
     <svg width="8000px" height="32000px">
      ....
     </svg>
   </div>
  </div>
```

And the following CSS applied to it:

```
#graphic {
  width: 768px;
  height: 1004px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#wrap {
  width: 768px;
  height: 1004px;
  -webkit-transform: scale(1) translate3d(0, 0, 0);
}
```

Using CSS3 Animations I want to pan / zoom on a very large svg graphic. It is working...kind of. I discovered a problem on the iPad that when setting the y-value of translate3d to below ~ 16500px the graphic is not displayed anymore (In Safari or Chrome it works totally fine). I thought that there might be a limit to the height / width of rendering SVGs on mobile Safari, but removing the overflow:hidden from the #graphic container lets me scroll all the way down and everything it displayed correctly.

Has anyone heard of or experienced similar limitations / Is there some CSS value I have to set for this whole think to work? Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you have hit a limit. Translate3D'd elements must fit into GPU texture memory, and when you "over or under translate" this can cause the whole texture to be dumped. See the [Apple documentation on texture memory limitations.](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/3DDrawing/Conceptual/OpenGLES_ProgrammingGuide/OpenGLESPlatforms/OpenGLESPlatforms.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008793-CH106-SW3)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. So I guess there is not even some hacky way "overcome" this limit?

Comment: There are a few possible solutions - 1st is not to use translate, use position changes instead. 2nd is to chop up the image into a grid of sub-images - this *might* work

Comment: Hi Michael, I was thinking of using translate3d for hardware acceleration, so using position is not really an option. Choping the images into a grid didn't work either, since the images are all in the same container having this limit

Comment: This is not an answer to your question, sorry about that, but there is a reason why Google uses tiles, loads incoming tiles when they are just outside the viewport, and unloads them when they are outside again. It is a bit of waste of memory keeping a whole 10k pixel image on the page.